# Exponential compilation times with simple typelist implementation. Why?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying my hand at C++ type lists. Below is a trivial implementation of a type list filter function. It seems to work except that compilation times in both gcc and clang are horrific beyond say 18 elements. I was wondering what improvements I could make to make this practical.

```
#include <type_traits>

// a type list
template <class... T> struct tl ;

// helper filter for type list 
template <class IN_TL, class OUT_TL, template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl;

// Base case
template <class... Ts, template <typename> class P>
// If the input list is empty we are done
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<>, tl<Ts...>, P> {
  using type = tl<Ts...>;
};

// Normal case
template <class Head, class... Tail, class... Ts2, template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<Head, Tail...>, tl<Ts2...>, P> {
  using type = typename std::conditional<
      // Does the predicate hold on the head of the input list?
      P<Head>::value,
      // The head of the input list matches our predictate, copy it
      typename filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2..., Head>, P>::type,
      // The head of the input list does not match our predicate, skip
      // it
      typename filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2...>, P>::type>::type;
};

template <class TL, template <typename> class P> struct filter_tl {
  using type = typename filter_tl_impl<TL, tl<>, P>::type;
};

// Test code
using MyTypes = tl<
   char*, bool, char, int, long, void,
   char*, bool, char, int, long, void,
   char*, bool, char, int, long, void
   >;


using MyNumericTypes = filter_tl<MyTypes, std::is_arithmetic>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same < MyNumericTypes,
              tl<
              bool,char,int,long,
              bool,char,int,long,
              bool,char,int,long
              >> :: value);

int main(int, char **) {}
```

Comment: I am sorry but if you have beyond 18 elements you are creating over 60 different classes, not primitive data types mind you, classes, what makes you think the time to run that program would be fast??

Comment: @YunfeiChen do you live in 1957?

Comment: Hmmm what you are doing is similar to creating 60 different files and defining 60 different header files and making them..... Try it, you get an ugly directory that takes forever to run...... To put it into perspective....

Comment: That isn't it Yunfei. 60 simple classes in a single file take no time to compile at all. As Jarod42 and HTNW below discuss there is something wrong with my recursion where both branches get taken which leads to ~2^18 classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using type = typename std::conditional<
      // Does the predicate hold on the head of the input list?
      P<Head>::value,
      // The head of the input list matches our predictate, copy it
      typename filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2..., Head>, P>::type,
      // The head of the input list does not match our predicate, skip
      // it
      typename filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2...>, P>::type>::type;
```

instantiates both sides because of `::type`.

You might delay intermediate instantiation by after the `std::conditional`:

```
using type = typename std::conditional<
      // Does the predicate hold on the head of the input list?
      P<Head>::value,
      // The head of the input list matches our predicate, copy it
      filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2..., Head>, P>,
      // The head of the input list does not match our predicate, skip
      // it
      filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>, tl<Ts2...>, P>>::type::type;
```

Which leads to linear number of instantiations instead of exponential.

Comment: Man, thanks a ton. That changes makes the compilation instantaneous. I do not understand it though. Could you elaborate a bit on why this works?

Comment: The original algorithm is `O(2^n)`. The new one is `O(n)`. In your code, if you start `filter_tl_impl` with `sizeof...(Tails) == n`, then you recursively call `filter_tl_impl` twice, each with `sizeof...(Tails) == n - 1`, and which leads to 4 total calls (2 per call at the previous layer) with `sizeof...(Tails) == n - 2`, etc. leading to a final `2^n` calls to the base case (`sizeof...(Tails) == 0`). Thus the entire thing took `O(2^n)` (I think about `2^(n + 1)`?) calls. In this version, each call to `filter_tl_impl` recurses at most once, bringing us back down to `O(n)` calls. `2^18 >>> 18`.

Comment: Thanks HTNW but why are both sides being instantiated? Shouldn't the conditional limit the instantiation to just one of them?

Comment: No. At the least, we must check that neither branch errors, and that entails simplifying them fully. There's also the issue of commoning up specializations: `std::conditional<true, std::type_identity<int>, float>` must be the *exact same type* as `std::conditional<true, int, float>`, which is easiest done by simplifying `std::type_identity<int>` down to `int` before specializing `std::conditional`. Remember that `std::conditional` is just a normal class template. It's not like `if`/`else` or `? :`. It's a function `Type conditional(bool b, Type, Type)`, which only takes evaluated arguments.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want lists, the first thing you do is define the `cons` function. The rest becomes natural and straightforward.

```
// first, define `cons`      
  template <class Head, class T> struct cons_impl;
  template <class Head, class ... Tail>
  struct cons_impl <Head, tl<Tail...>> {
     using type = tl<Head, Tail...>;
  };
  template <class Head, class T>
  using cons = typename cons_impl<Head, T>::type;

// next, define `filter`
  template <template <typename> class P, class T>
  struct filter_tl_impl;
  template <template <typename> class P, class T>
  using filter_tl = typename filter_tl_impl<P, T>::type;

// empty list case      
  template <template <typename> class P>
  struct filter_tl_impl<P, tl<>> {
    using type = tl<>;
  };
  
// non-empty lust case
  template <template <typename> class P, class Head, class ... Tail>
  struct filter_tl_impl<P, tl<Head, Tail...>> {
    using tailRes = filter_tl<P, tl<Tail...>>;
    using type = std::conditional_t<P<Head>::value,
                                    cons<Head, tailRes>,
                                    tailRes>;
  };
```

Note tailRes is defined for readability only, you can write directly

```
    using type = std::conditional_t<P<Head>::value,
                                    cons<Head, filter_tl<P, tl<Tail...>>>,
                                    filter_tl<P, tl<Tail...>>>;
```

and compilation time remains negligible.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative could be insert the `std::conditional` inside the `filter_tl_impl`.

I mean

```
// Normal case
template <typename Head, typename... Tail, typename... Ts2,
          template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<Head, Tail...>, tl<Ts2...>, P>
 {
   using type = typename filter_tl_impl<tl<Tail...>,
                                        std::conditional_t<
                                           P<Head>::value,
                                           tl<Ts2..., Head>,
                                           tl<Ts2...>>,
                                        P>::type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

And now, for something completely different...

I propose to split your "normal case" (the recursive case) in two different cases: the case "true" and the case "false".

Unfortunately, this require an additional custom type traits `check_first`

```
template <typename, template <typename> class>
struct check_first : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename H, typename ... T, template <typename> class P>
struct check_first<tl<H, T...>, P>
   : public std::integral_constant<bool, P<H>::value>
 { };
```

Now you can write `filter_tl_impl` as follows

```
// declaration and ground case
template <typename I, typename O, template <typename> class P,
          bool = check_first<I, P>::value>
struct filter_tl_impl
 { using type = O; };

// recursive-positive case
template <typename H, typename... T, typename... Ts,
          template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<H, T...>, tl<Ts...>, P, true>
   : public filter_tl_impl<tl<T...>, tl<Ts..., H>, P>
 { };

// recursive-negative case
template <typename H, typename... T, typename... Ts,
          template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<H, T...>, tl<Ts...>, P, false>
   : public filter_tl_impl<tl<T...>, tl<Ts...>, P>
 { };
```

I've also rewritten `filter_tl` as a simpler `using`

```
template <typename TL, template <typename> class P>
using filter_tl = typename filter_tl_impl<TL, tl<>, P>::type;
```

so your original code become

```
#include <type_traits>

// a type list
template <typename...>
struct tl;

template <typename, template <typename> class>
struct check_first : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename H, typename ... T, template <typename> class P>
struct check_first<tl<H, T...>, P>
   : public std::integral_constant<bool, P<H>::value>
 { };   

// declaration and ground case
template <typename I, typename O, template <typename> class P,
          bool = check_first<I, P>::value>
struct filter_tl_impl
 { using type = O; };

// recursive-positive case
template <typename H, typename... T, typename... Ts,
          template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<H, T...>, tl<Ts...>, P, true>
   : public filter_tl_impl<tl<T...>, tl<Ts..., H>, P>
 { };

// recursive-negative case
template <typename H, typename... T, typename... Ts,
          template <typename> class P>
struct filter_tl_impl<tl<H, T...>, tl<Ts...>, P, false>
   : public filter_tl_impl<tl<T...>, tl<Ts...>, P>
 { };

template <typename TL, template <typename> class P>
using filter_tl = typename filter_tl_impl<TL, tl<>, P>::type;

// Test code
using MyTypes = tl<char*, bool, char, int, long, void,
                   char*, bool, char, int, long, void,
                   char*, bool, char, int, long, void>;

using MyNumericTypes = filter_tl<MyTypes, std::is_arithmetic>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyNumericTypes,
                             tl<bool, char, int, long,
                                bool, char, int, long,
                                bool, char, int, long>>);

int main ()
 { }
```

Comment: Different yes, but not really better don't you think?

Comment: @samwise - IMHO is better because split the recursive case in two different cases, so avoid, at the root, your compilation performance problem (the compiler choose one case or the other, not both). Take in count that, using a single case and `std::conditional` there is the risk to fall again in the preceding problem, if you change your code. But I admit that is less readable, and this could be a problem.